# How do I print a step variable in Radish test framework?

Tags: python, syntax, bdd

I want to print the tables and variables read from the feature file in the radish test case .

Is there anyway to print the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have steps defined (some context [code] would be nice to provide in your question), you have a few options. Ultimately, you'll need to use regular expressions to identify the locations of the variables, and then save them for later use.

Your choices are:

1. Create a list to contain your variables.
2. Print directly to file

Create list:

```py
var_list = []
@step("I have the number {number:g}")
def have_number(step, number):
    step.context.var_list.append(number)
```

or print to file:

```py
world.OutputPath = world.dirname + "your_file_name_here.txt"
file = open(world.OutputPath,mode='w+',  encoding="utf-8")
@step("I have the number {number:g}")
def have_number(step, number):
    file.write(number)
file.close()
```

Comment: strangely , printing the statement twice seems to work. But what you have mentioned is more logical , so will be using that.